# I did a bad job pouring a cement walkway, how can I fix it?

Tags: repair, concrete, level

I poured three 4'x4' slabs to make a walkway beside my house. The first two look alright but the third one is a half inch lower than the one next to it and slopes up at the open end where I want to pour six more slabs. Of course I wanted my slabs to slope down the walkway but my third slab slopes back the wrong way.

Is there something I can use to fill this half inch and get it to slope the right way, or at least make it somewhat level?

Comment: Do you have any pictures?

Comment: Yes, pictures, please hehe

Comment: If it is not engaged with the adjoining slab, and if you have a use for a 4x4 pad at another spot, then relocate it.  If you do not have another use for it, then for the next pad, excavate 3 inches deeper and move it there:  tilt it up; clean off most of the dirt; pour about 1" of concrete in the bottom of the new location (to provide uniform bearing);  lay it in place; then finally pour a 2" slab on top per @Bryce answer.

Answer (score 1):

A number of the low aggregate rapid set cements are good for applications down to  a 1/2 inch.  The patch is best made when the old cement is still fresh, and for good measure use some concrete bonding adhesive.